# how to disable previous date in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I have followed and tried this solution:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

but it doesnt work on my end.When click the datepicker the calendar pops out but i can select the previous dates.

I also included these references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

still no luck.

how am i going to solve this?
here's what i have so far:

VIEW

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
     <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control col-md-9 deliveryDate" style="margin-left: 19%;">
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: -20,
        maxDate: "+1M +10D"
    });
});
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are calling the wrong selector. Instead of calling `#datepicker2`, use `#datepicker` only

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: -20,
            maxDate: "+1M +10D"
        });
    });
```

Comment: i still got the sam result @johnroe

Comment: I have it running well.. IDK if i get your point but the code that you have provided is functional so to speak

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xh95ptag/):

For disabling previous dates , write

```
 minDate: 0
```

For disabling next dates , write

```
 maxDate: 0
```

One more thing , your `id selector` is wrong . Should be the same as the one you have for `input`

Hope it help !

Comment: Hav u included jquery library and jquery.ui.js ?

Comment: i am not sure but can you tell me which version are you using for both ?